# First two values in .Random.seed are always the same with different set.seed()s

Tags: r, random, random-seed

### Preamble

I've looked through other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687354/set-seed-and-random-seed-in-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712157/r-bizarre-behavior-of-set-seed), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997444/print-the-current-random-seed-so-that-i-can-enter-it-with-set-seed-later)) describing the use and function of `set.seed()` and `.Random.seed` and can't find this particular issue documented so here it is as a question:

### Inital Observation

When I inspect the `.Random.seed`s generated as a result of `set.seed(1)` and `set.seed(2)`, I find that the first two elements are always the same (`10403` & `624`) while the rest appears not to be. See example below.

### My questions

1. Is that expected?
2. Why does it happen?
3. Will this have any untoward consequenses for any random simulation I
   might do based on it?

### Reproducible Example

```r
f <- function(s1, s2){
  
  set.seed(s1)
  r1 <- .Random.seed
  set.seed(s2)
  r2 <- .Random.seed
  
  print(r1[1:3])
  print(r2[1:3])
  
  plot(r1, r2)
  
}

f(1, 2)
#> [1]      10403        624 -169270483
#> [1]       10403         624 -1619336578
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that the first two elements of each `.Random.seed` are identical but the remainder is not. You can see in the scatterplot that it's just a random cloud as expected.

Comment: From [`?.Random.seed`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html), it says that the *"first element _codes_ the kind of RNG and normal generator"*, so the first value is unlikely to change unless one changes the generator method (`RNGkind`). For me, `.Random.seed[2]` indicates the number of draws (so `runif(2)` increments the second integer by 2), but this second value is set to `624` when I `set.seed(.)`. Seems like that's intentional, though I cannot find docs for it. The rest contains the RNG state.

Comment: The default random number generator is "Mersenne-Twister" which "the ‘seed’ is a 624-dimensional set of integers". It appears when set.seed() is called the index (ie the 2nd value) is set to the max value of 624 so that when the index is incremented to create the next random number it starts back at 1.

Comment: could these comments be worked into an answer instead?

Comment: Thanks all, this is great. The only other information I'd like in an answer would be how `.Random.seed` gets used by random processes (e.g. `rnorm()`) to demonstrate why those first two values being semi-constant won't affect simulation results.

Comment: I couldn't find any information on the mechanics of how random processes actually use `.Random.seed` and therefore how they know to avoid the first element in the vector, but if anyone does, please feel free to add it to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding helpful comments from @r2evans and @Dave2e into an answer.

### 1) .Random.seed[1]

From [`?.Random.seed`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html), it says:

> "`.Random.seed` is an integer vector whose first element *codes* the
> kind of RNG and normal generator. The lowest two decimal digits are in
> `0:(k-1)` where `k` is the number of available RNGs. The hundreds
> represent the type of normal generator (starting at 0), and the ten
> thousands represent the type of discrete uniform sampler."

Therefore the first value doesn't change unless one changes the generator method (`RNGkind`).

Here is a small demonstration of this for each of the available `RNGkind`s:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# available RNGkind options
kinds <- c(
  "Wichmann-Hill",
  "Marsaglia-Multicarry",
  "Super-Duper",
  "Mersenne-Twister",
  "Knuth-TAOCP-2002",
  "Knuth-TAOCP",
  "L'Ecuyer-CMRG"
)
# test over multiple seeds
seeds <- c(1:3)

f <- function(kind, seed) {
  # set seed with simulation parameters
  set.seed(seed = seed, kind = kind)
  # check value of first element in .Random.seed
  return(.Random.seed[1])
}

# run on simulated conditions and compare value over different seeds
expand_grid(kind = kinds, seed = seeds) %>%
  pmap(f) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  matrix(
    ncol = length(seeds),
    byrow = T,
    dimnames = list(kinds, paste0("seed_", seeds))
  )

#>                      seed_1 seed_2 seed_3
#> Wichmann-Hill         10400  10400  10400
#> Marsaglia-Multicarry  10401  10401  10401
#> Super-Duper           10402  10402  10402
#> Mersenne-Twister      10403  10403  10403
#> Knuth-TAOCP-2002      10406  10406  10406
#> Knuth-TAOCP           10404  10404  10404
#> L'Ecuyer-CMRG         10407  10407  10407
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### 2) .Random.seed[2]

At least for the default `"Mersenne-Twister"` method, `.Random.seed[2]` is an index that indicates the current position in the random set. From the docs:

> The ‘seed’ is a 624-dimensional set of 32-bit integers plus a current
> position in that set.

This is updated when random processes using the seed are executed. However for other methods it the documentation doesn't mention something like this and there doesn't appear to be a clear trend in the same way.

See below for an example of changes in `.Random.seed[2]` over iterative random process after `set.seed()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# available RNGkind options
kinds <- c(
  "Wichmann-Hill",
  "Marsaglia-Multicarry",
  "Super-Duper",
  "Mersenne-Twister",
  "Knuth-TAOCP-2002",
  "Knuth-TAOCP",
  "L'Ecuyer-CMRG"
)

# create function to run random process and report .Random.seed[2]
t <- function(n = 1) {
  p <- .Random.seed[2]
  runif(n)
  p
}

# create function to set seed and iterate a random process
f2 <- function(kind, seed = 1, n = 5) {
  
  set.seed(seed = seed,
           kind = kind)

  replicate(n, t())
}

# set simulation parameters
trials <- 5
seeds <- 1:2
x <- expand_grid(kind = kinds, seed = seeds, n = trials) 

# evaluate and report
x %>% 
  pmap_dfc(f2) %>% 
  mutate(n = paste0("trial_", 1:trials)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-n, names_to = "row") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "n") %>% 
  select(-row) %>% 
  bind_cols(x[,1:2], .)


#> # A tibble: 14 x 7
#>    kind                  seed    trial_1     trial_2     trial_3 trial_4 trial_5
#>    <chr>                <int>      <int>       <int>       <int>   <int>   <int>
#>  1 Wichmann-Hill            1      23415        8457       23504  2.37e4  2.28e4
#>  2 Wichmann-Hill            2      21758       27800        1567  2.58e4  2.37e4
#>  3 Marsaglia-Multicarry     1 1280795612   945095059    14912928  1.34e9  2.23e8
#>  4 Marsaglia-Multicarry     2 -897583247 -1953114152  2042794797  1.39e9  3.71e8
#>  5 Super-Duper              1 1280795612 -1162609806 -1499951595  5.51e8  6.35e8
#>  6 Super-Duper              2 -897583247   224551822     -624310 -2.23e8  8.91e8
#>  7 Mersenne-Twister         1        624           1           2  3       4     
#>  8 Mersenne-Twister         2        624           1           2  3       4     
#>  9 Knuth-TAOCP-2002         1  166645457   504833754   504833754  5.05e8  5.05e8
#> 10 Knuth-TAOCP-2002         2  967462395   252695483   252695483  2.53e8  2.53e8
#> 11 Knuth-TAOCP              1 1050415712   999978161   999978161  1.00e9  1.00e9
#> 12 Knuth-TAOCP              2  204052929   776729829   776729829  7.77e8  7.77e8
#> 13 L'Ecuyer-CMRG            1 1280795612  -169270483  -442010614  4.71e8  1.80e9
#> 14 L'Ecuyer-CMRG            2 -897583247 -1619336578  -714750745  2.10e9 -9.89e8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here you can see that from the `Mersenne-Twister` method, `.Random.seed[2]` increments from it's maximum of `624` back to `1` and **increased by the size of the random draw** and that this is the same for `set.seed(1)` and `set.seed(2)`. However the same trend is not seen in the other methods. To illustrate the last point, see that `runif(1)` increments `.Random.seed[2]` by `1` while `runif(2)` increments it by `2`:

```r
# create function to run random process and report .Random.seed[2]
t <- function(n = 1) {
  p <- .Random.seed[2]
  runif(n)
  p
}

set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
replicate(9, t(1))
#> [1] 624   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8

set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
replicate(5, t(2))
#> [1] 624   2   4   6   8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### 3) Sequential Randoms

Because the index or state of `.Random.seed` (apparently for all the RNG methods) advances according to the size of the 'random draw' (number of random values genearted from the `.Random.seed`), it is possible to generate the same series of random numbers from the same seed in different sized increments. Furthermore, as long as you run the same random process at the same point in the sequence after setting the same seed, it seems that you will get the same result.  Observe the following example:

```r
# draw 3 at once
set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
sample(100, 3, T)
#> [1] 68 39  1

# repeat single draw 3 times
set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
sample(100, 1)
#> [1] 68
sample(100, 1)
#> [1] 39
sample(100, 1)
#> [1] 1

# draw 1, do something else, draw 1 again
set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
sample(100, 1)
#> [1] 68
runif(1)
#> [1] 0.5728534
sample(100, 1)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### 4) Correlated Randoms

As we saw above, two random processes run at the same point after setting the same seed are expected to give the same result. However, even when you provide constraints on how similar the result can be (e.g. by changing the `mean` of `rnorm()` or even by providing different functions) it seems that the results are still perfectly correlated within their respective ranges.

```r
# same function with different constraints
set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
a <- runif(50, 0, 1)

set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
b <- runif(50, 10, 100)

plot(a, b)
```

[image]

```r
# different functions
set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
d <- rnorm(50)

set.seed(1, kind = "Mersenne-Twister")
e <- rlnorm(50)

plot(d, e)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>